# Chord symbols in staff in Sibelius

Tags: guitar, notation, sibelius

When I write guitar parts in Sibelius I currently use a slash notation (4 slashes with no stems in each measure and chord symbols above staff), but I want to make it even simpler for my guitarist and just put chord symbols straight into the staff by default and switch to slashes only when I need to notate some specific rhythm.

Is this possible/easy to do?

(I own a licence for the Artist edition of Sibelius)